# Core data debugger hangs at assigning value to entity

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a core data entity to which I am trying to assign relationship from another entity. Please refer the code below

```
#define kId @"id"

-(NSArray *)fetchObjectsForEntityName:(NSString *)entityName withPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *newContext = [Helper generateNewContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:newContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest new];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    if (predicate)
        [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *resultArray = [newContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    return resultArray;
}

-(void)updateCoreDataEntity
{
    NSArray *objectsArray = [self fetchObjectsForEntityName:@"FirstEntity" withPredicate:nil];

//FirstObjects is a subclass of NSManagedObject class (Custom entity)
//kId is just #define as defined above
//Recasting removed

        for (FirstObjects *firstObject in objectsArray) {
            if ([firstObject.id isEqualToString:[dict valueForKey:kId]]) {
                     secondEntity.firstEntity = firstObject; //debugger hangs here  
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to fetch objects that belong to "FirstEntity" into an NSArray

Loop through that array to find the required object.

Then assign the "firstObject" to SecondEntity if the criteria matches.

However, I am getting nowhere with this code as the debugger (and the code) hangs at the last line of code.

What is the mistake I am doing, can anyone help with this code.

Regards,

iSee

Comment: What is the FirstObject class? What is dict? What is unreadArray? Why is the id attribute a string? Where and how is kId defined? What is unreadcCountNew? Why are you recasting managedObject? etc, etc... Your question is not clear. Try to simplify!

Comment: @Mundi, I hope the updated code is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`secondEntity` is maybe undefined. This would surely lead to a crash.

Also, the logic of the ID is flawed. It seems the comparison is not comparing to a specific ID but to the generic string "id". Perhaps you really want to compare to a dynamically allocated id? Also, are these string ids unique? (If not you might get unpredictable results.)

Finally, from the code it is not clear if Helper provides always the **same** managed object context. This would be strongly advised - separate contexts are mainly used for concurrency.

Comment: Yes! the last line in your answer was the problem. The Helper only checked if the thread was a main thread or not before giving a new instance of NSManagedObjectContext. This fixed it.

I couldn't post the production code for obvious reasons and this lead to the confusion. Thank you for taking your time to read through the half baked code, understanding it and providing the answer.